# Primary key or regular field in database for deleting a row?

Tags: sql, primary-key, sql-delete

I want to erase a row in my database, I have 2 options; first to use a normal column to delete the row, second, the primary key?

I know that primary key is better, but why?

Comment: Because it's the primary key that uniquely identifies your row. If you're specifying another column, then you run the risk of (a) deleting more than one row, and (b) usually you have to either do a table scan to find the row by an arbitrary column value, or you need to first look up that value in a secondary index and then find the row based on the primary key value and then delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key is better because you are sure what row you are deleting: although technically you can update a primary key column, it is not a normal practice to do so. Other columns, however, are changeable, which could lead to situations like this:

- You have a table with a `PK` and another unique identifier, say, `email`
- You read a row with email `sample_email@gmail.com`, and decide to delete it
- The row gets modified concurrently, with the e-mail updated to `simple_email@gmail.com`
- You execute the `DELETE USER WHERE email='sample_email@gmail.com'`

The `DELETE` command does not delete anything, because the e-mail has been changed before you managed to run your command. Since `PK` is not supposed to change, this situation would not be possible under normal circumstances. Of course your code can detect that deletion did not happen, redo the read, and re-issue the command, but that is a lot of work compared to using a primary key.

Comment: This seems like a good example of why *not* to use the primary key in all cases. In your example, if the intention was to delete the user with the specified email address and that email address changes then perhaps the correct and safest action is *not* to delete the row. The same operation based on the user's primary key at some point in time might not have had the same effect.

Comment: @sqlvogel Deletion almost universally targets specific entities, as opposed to entities with specific properties. My point was that deletion on a PK lets you target a specific entity, while deletion on non-PK columns does not let you target a specific entity as reliably.

Comment: In a relational database an entity is identifiable only by its (key) attributes. That an entity can be more reliably identified by "primary" key attributes than by other key attributes is a conjecture. In practice it depends on the choice of attributes and the intentions of the designer and user.

Comment: @sqlvogel The fact that designers add PKs for the purpose of identifying entities by something other than their meaningful attributes (I am not talking about corner situations when you can use a combination of one or more "meaningful" attribute as your PK) transforms a "conjecture" into a "self fulfilling prophecy". The fact that multiple highly successful ORM solutions exist that allow deletion only by a PK gives a lot of support to the "conjecture" as well. In theory, designer choices are not limited; in practice, designers tend to make the same choice when the choice works well.

Comment: So your answer is based on an assumption about what the OP has chosen as his PK as well as on what the intended effect of his delete is. I agree. I just prefer to have these things in the open rather than as unstated assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

On MySql you can face strange locking behaviour in multiuser environment when deleting/updating rows using non-primary key columns.
Here is an example - two sessions trying to delete rows (autocommit is disabled).

```
C:\mysql\bin>mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.29-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

mysql> create table test(
    ->   id int primary key,
    ->   val int
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

......

mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
|  4 |    4 |
|  5 |    5 |
|  6 |    6 |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now in session 1 we will delete row #5 using primary key

```
mysql> delete from test where id = 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

and then in session 2 we delete row #2 using PK too

```
mysql> set autocommit=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from test where id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Everything looks OK - row #5 was deleted by session 1 and row #2 deleted in session 2

And now look what will happen when we wil try to delete rows using non primary key:

Session 1

```
mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from test where val = 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

and session 2

```
mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from test where val = 2;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
mysql>
```

Delete command in session 2 "hangs", and after a minute or so it throws an error: Lock wait timeout
Lets try to delete others rows:

```
mysql> delete from test where val = 4;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
mysql> delete from test where val = 6;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
mysql>
```

Session 1 deletes only row #5, and, logically, a lock shuould be placed only on record #5 beying deleted, but as you can see in these examples, when not using primary key, MySql placed locks on **all rows of the whole table**.  So it is safer to delete rows using only primary key (at least on MySql).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean a statement like this:

```
delete from table
    where column = value
```

When the column is a primary key, it automatically has a unique index on it (at least in the databases I know of).  This makes it fast to find the record to be deleted.

Another column with an index would be almost as fast, because it could use an index lookup.

A column without an index would be much slower, because the query would have to do a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Rows are uniquely identified by *superkeys*, including candidate keys. The primary key is one candidate key, but not necessarily the only one.

There's no fundamental reason why the primary key must always be a "better" way to specify an update, delete or other operation. Use whichever attributes best express the intended update, especially bearing in mind that some attribute values may be subject to change. Very often a primary key is chosen as such because it is a candidate key thought unlikely to change or alternatively because it is the "preferred" identifier for updates.

Suppose a table has two keys: j and k, where k is designated the primary key. If a user actually wanted to perform an update based on the value of j: `DELETE ... WHERE j=123;` then depending on the effective transaction isolation level and the stability of *either* attribute that update could express a quite different intention from a similar update based on the corresponding value of k at some point in time. This is true whichever attribute is subject to change. So if you are concerned about the effect of changing key values then you should consider which choice of key(s) best expresses the user's intended update. Assuming candidate key value changes are rare anyway then using a designated primary key for all updates is typically the "default" assumption because consistently using the same key makes coding simpler.